# org.kohsuke Github API Use

Tags: java, git, api

When  I use `org.kohsuke` GitHubub API to get some information, there is a bug.

```
    GitHub gitHub = GitHub.connectUsingOAuth(token);



    GHCommit ghCommit=gitHub.getRepository("select2/select2").getCommit("7303852862575de61a70d3fa71dd3d5b59ea85af");

    GHUser ghUser=ghCommit.getAuthor();
    System.out.print(ghCommit.getAuthor().getName());
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   HtmlReference.GitHtmlAnalyseThroAPI.main(GitHtmlAnalyseThroAPI.java:64)

Another way to say, ghUser is null. I do not know the reason.Anyone would help?

By the way,I am sure commitId and projectName is right..
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33fct.png)

Comment: I don't understand why is this an issue?`getAuthor()` can return null. You have to do a null check on `ghuser` before calling `getName()`

Comment: But the result should not be null. Right? I do get the result(!null) through browser using the same parameter

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your  path is correct? I thought you have it as `select2/select2/commits` in the attached image.

Comment: Path is correct.I change my code.When I use   String sha1=ghCommit.getSHA1();I can get the sha1 valuse which proves that ghCommit is not null.  I do not understand why i can not get author.

Answer (score 0):

I do change another pair of parameter.

```
GHCommit ghCommit=gitHub.getRepository("select2/select2").getCommit("3fb9e4fceb43d4520f7a6fc7d842abeceb8ddf50");

    GHUser ghUser=ghCommit.getAuthor();

    if(ghUser==null){
        System.out.print("null");
    }
    else
        System.out.print(ghUser.getName());
```

I get a result which is not null.I guess this may be a single issue that i do not know why.